# testing active record associations on models Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, unit-testing, activerecord, models

I tried to seed a database to test associations with active record methods in the rails console. This wasn't a good approach as I would manually have to add all the references and foreign keys. This is how I used to test relations with `ruby/sinatra/sql`.

Anyone know how to do some setups for test files in rails, to test associations the proper way? This is `JobEntry` test file, it is the main table. `Chargeable` `belongs_to` `JobEntry`. Runnning `rake test` gets me nowhere at the moment, lots of errors.

Here's what I have so far:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'active_support/core_ext/module/delegation'

module Shoulda
  module Matchers
    module ActiveRecord

class JobEntryTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
   @job_entry = JobEntry.new( material: "Ashgrove suilven", size_width: 42, size_height: 12, units: 'in',
       runs: 1, prints: 1, margin: 0, per_print: 0, discount: 0.05, price: 34.20,
       originals: 1)
 end


should has_many(:chargeables)


  test "materials" do
    assert_equal "Ashgrove suilven", @job_entry.material
  end
end


require 'test_helper'
require 'active_support/core_ext/module/delegation'
module Shoulda
  module Matchers
    module ActiveRecord

class ChargeableTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

shoulda belongs_to(:job_entry)

end
```

Am I on the right track with this?

Comment: You can test that an association exists without creating any instances by using [reflection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html). Other than that your question is far too broad.

Comment: Testing associations is pretty specific, I think. It's one self-contained thing. I don't know how to make it more specific.